# Spring - Dynamic factory based on enum

Tags: java, spring, enums, factory

I have the following classes:

```
public enum TaskType {

    VERIFY_X_TASK, COMPUTE_Y_TASK, PROCESS_Z_TASK;
}

public interface Task{
    void process();
}

@Component
public class VerifyXTask implements Task{
    // Similar classes for the other types of tasks
    public void process() {
    }
}

@Component
public class TaskFactory{
    private Map<TaskType, Task> tasks;
    public Task getTask(TaskType type){
        return tasks.get(type); // return a singleton with all it's fields injected by the application context
    }
}

class UseTool{
    @Autowired
    private TaskFactory taskFactory;

    public void run(String taskType){
        Task task = taskFactory.getTask(TaskType.valueOf(taskType));
        task.process();
    }
}
```

What is the most elegant way of injecting the association between TaskType and Task into the factory?
Consider that there are almost 100 task types and that these may change quite frequently.

--
Further explanations:
I could do in the TaskFactory class smth like:

```
tasks.put(TaskType.VERIFY_X_TASK, new VerifyTask());
tasks.put(TaskType.COMPUTE_Y_TASK, new ComputeTask());
tasks.put(TaskType.PROCESS_Z_TASK, new ProcessTask());
```

But this does not inject any properties in the Task object.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do; why do you have an `enum` that's a list of operations and then not have any sort of relationship between the `enum` values and the implementing classes?

Comment: The question is how to map this relationship. I could do in the factory smth like tasks.put(VERIFY_X_TASK, new VerifyTask()); and so on but the new operator will not inject the VerifyTasks dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following approach:

1. Define a custom annotation `@ImplementsTask` that takes a `TaskType` as a parameter, so that you can write your implementation class like this:

   ```
   @Component
   @ImplementsTask(TaskType.VERIFY_X_TASK)
   public class VerifyXTask implements Task {
   ...
   ```

   (Or you can meta-annotate `@Component` to avoid having to use it on all the classes.)
2. Inject all of the identified `Task` objects into your factory:

   ```
   @Autowired
   private Set<Task> scannedTasks;
   ```
3. In a `@PostConstruct` method on the factory, iterate over each of the elements in `scannedTasks`, reading the annotation value and adding a `Map` entry (to an `EnumMap`, of course). You'll need to decide how to deal with duplicate implementations for a given `TaskType`.

This will require a bit of reflection work in the factory setup, but it means that you can just annotate a `Task` implementation with the appropriate value and have it scanned in without any additional work by the implementor.

Comment: Very elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got into similar kind of problem to solve, what I really did is, It may be helpful.

Define Tasks Enum like.

```
public enum Tasks {
    Task1(SubTasks.values());

    Tasks(PagesEnumI[] pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    PagesEnumI[] pages;
    // define setter and getter
}
```

Defined Subtask like

```
public interface PagesEnumI {
    String getName();
    String getUrl();
}

public enum SubTasks implements PagesEnumI {
    Home("home_url");

    SubTasks(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    private String url;

    @Override
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name();
    }
}
```

Defined Service to call per SubTasks enum like

```
public interface PageI {
    void process();
    Sites getTaskName();
    PagesEnumI getSubTaskName();
}

@Component
public class Home implements PageI {

    // function per SubTask to process
    @Override
    public void process() {}

    // to get the information about Main Task
    @Override
    public Tasks getTaskName() {
        return Tasks.Task1;
    }

    // to get the information about Sub Task
    @Override
    public PagesEnumI getSubTaskName() {
        return Task1.Home;
    }
}
```

Define a factory like...

```
@Component
public class PageFactory {

    Set<PageI> pages;
    // HashMap for keeping objects into
    private static HashMap<String, PageI> pagesFactory = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    public void setPages(Set<PageI> pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    // construct key by 
    private static String constructKey(Tasks taks, PagesEnumI page) {
        return task.name() + "__" + page.getName();
    }

    // PostConstruct means after construct class object this method should get run
    // iterating over all pages and storing into Map
    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        for (PageI pageI : pages) {
            pagesFactory.put(constructKey(pageI.getTaskName(), pageI.getSubTaskName()), pageI);
        }
    }

    // getting object from factory
    public PageI getPageObject(Tasks task, PagesEnumI page) {
        return pagesFactory.get(constructKey(task, page));
    }
}
```

Till now we have registered our enum(Tasks and SunTasks) and their service(With getter of Tasks and SubTasks), Now defining a factory to call service `process` method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    PageFactory factory;

    @Autowired
    public void setFactory(PageFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // for each task we might have different sub task
        Arrays.stream(Tasks.values()).forEach(
            task -> {
                // for each and subtask of a task need to perform process
                for (PagesEnumI page : task.getPages()) {
                    PageI pageI = factory.getPageObject(task, page);
                    pageI.process();
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

This is not exact similar problem, way to solve it may be similar. So I thought this might be helpful to put it here. Please don't by putting name, just trying to understand concept. If anyone have more inputs, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Let Task tell the factory which TaskType it supports.

It can be done using a plain old Java method, no Spring annotations required.

```
public interface Task {
    void process();
    TaskType supportedType();
}

@Component
public class VerifyXTask implements Task {    
    @Override
    public void process() {
    }

    @Override
    public TaskType supportedType() {
        return TaskType.VERIFY_X_TASK;
    }
}

@Component
public class TaskFactory {    
    private Map<TaskType, Task> tasks;

    public TaskFactory(List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Task::supportedType, Function.identity()));
    }

    public Task getTask(TaskType type) {
        return tasks.get(type);
    }
}
```